# Linux Driver needed to use Matrox TripleHead2Go Digital signal splitter

Tags: linux, drivers, display, splitter

I have 3 monitors and am trying to get the Matrox TripleHead2Go Digital signal splitter with my Linux workstation.  When I connect them all I get are blinking green lights on the monitors which I think means no signal.  Do I need to download a Linux driver?  I've searched online but can't find anything.  Maybe the problem is something else.  Same happens when trying to connect to my PC.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem installing these on Windows when I didn't use the supplied video cables.

As for the software utility, try contacting Matrox, they claim that there is software support available for some versions of Linux

[Contact Matrox](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/contact/)

Comment: I have used longer cables with the DVI version with success for a contract job for a video DJ.